# SVG doesn't respect background-size 100% 100%

Tags: css, image, svg, background-image

I have [this SVG image](https://www.mnkylab.com/tmp/bg.svg) that I would like to cover a complete container, keeping its distinctive edges. `background-size: 100% 100%;` seems like the perfect choice and while it works for regular images, it doesn't work in this case. Why?

(jpeg taken from [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7073919/james)' answer)

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.container {
  margin: 20px; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #000;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.container.svg {
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/RWM.svg);
}
.container.img {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/370799/pexels-photo-370799.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350);
}
```

```html
<div class="container svg">
  some<br>content<br>makes<br>this<br>large
</div>
<div class="container img">
  some<br>content<br>makes<br>this<br>large
</div>
```

Comment: This is confusing, What do you mean by fill the entire area rather than covering it ?

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa `cover` scales the image proportionally, but my image has very specific edges and I want to keep all of them visible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out after reading a couple of other threads - including ones where it worked.

The culprit was `viewBox` within the definition of the `<svg>`. When I removed it, the image scales as it should. And for safari I needed to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

Before:

```
<svg width="392px" height="499px" viewBox="0 0 392 499" ...
```

After:

```
<svg width="392px" height="499px" preserveAspectRatio="none" ...
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.container {
  margin: 20px; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #000;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.container.svg {
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/RWM.svg);
}
.container.img {
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/RWv.svg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container svg">
  some<br>content<br>makes<br>this<br>large
</div>
<div class="container img">
  some<br>content<br>makes<br>this<br>large
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`background-size: 100% 100%;` should do your trick. Please check if you have no errors in code.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7pn3cvh3/

Comment: It [doesn't work with my SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/7pn3cvh3/2/), I'll rephrase the question

Comment: In this case, you could do this in three ways: 1. export it as high-res PNG ant it will still be good quality, and will work with background-size: 100% 100%; 2. Divide the SVG to two SVG's (vertical and horizontal) and use them as :before and :after elements in CSS with background-position: contain; 3. use jQuery to measure the height of div and output the dimensions to the DOM as style="background-size: ***px ***px";

Comment: I like the SVGs for their small size, so high res PNG isn't really an option. Anyway, removing `viewBox` from the code did the trick